# swift in objective-c project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I am trying to include swift code in my objective-c project.I made a simple class with a tableview with all connections made through .xib such as datasource and delegate.I also  have written the datasource and delegate methods in my class but the app calls only the didload method.The number of rows and cell for row index at path  methods are never called .Can someone help me out with this issue?

Comment: set delegate and datasource for tableview

Comment: I have already set the delegate and datasource

Comment: ok...so put some code ...so we can check if any problem is there

Comment: There is nothing new

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 5;
    }
    
  
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let tcell=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
        tcell.textLabel?.text="Text"
        return tcell;
    }

Comment: There is nothing new.I've connected the delegate and datasource through xib and i've implemented the codes but it is not even calling number of rows.It just loads a blank screen.. remember this is a swift class in a total objective-c project

Answer (score 0):

Try to add datasource and delegate through code

```
tableView.delegate=self
tableView.datasource=self
```